# How can I prove that: $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(3n)}{(1*2)(4*5)(7*8)...(3n-2)*(3n-1)} = 3^n$

Tags: induction

How can I prove that:
$$\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(3n)}{(1 * 2)(4*5)(7*8)...(3n-2)*(3n-1)} = 3^n$$

Can you help me and explain me how can I prove it? I thought to prove it by induction, but I don't have idea how to do it in fact.

Comment: You can do it by induction.  Ask yourself, how does the left-hand side change when you go from $n$ to $n+1$?  How does the numerator change?  How does the denominator change?

Comment: If you "WantToKnowMath", then you gotta start *doing* math, and stop always asking others to *do your math assignments for you* once in a while!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

- $(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)…(3n)=\frac{(3n)!}{n!}$
- $(1\cdot2)(4\cdot5)(7\cdot8)…(3n-2)\cdot(3n-1)=\frac{(3n-1)!}{3\cdot6\cdot9\cdot...\cdot(3n-3)}=\frac{(3n-1)!}{3^{n-1}(n-1)!}$

thus

$$\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)…(3n)}{(1\cdot2)(4\cdot5)(7\cdot8)…(3n-2)\cdot(3n-1)} = \frac{(3n)!}{n!}\frac{3^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(3n-1)!}=\\=3^{n-1}\frac{(3n)!}{(3n-1)!}\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}=3^{n-1}\cdot\frac{3n}n=3^n$$

Comment: can you explain why it's true?

Comment: @WantToKnowMath all terms cancel out, I add some detail

Comment: I don't understand the first step

Comment: I add further details

Comment: I don't understand the role of $3^{n-1}$ in the first step

Comment: @WantToKnowMath I've added the derivation for all terms

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(3n)}{(1\cdot2)(4\cdot5)(7\cdot8)...(3n-2)\cdot(3n-1)}=$$
$$=\frac{3^n\cdot n!(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(3n)}{(1\cdot2)3(4\cdot5)6(7\cdot8)...(3n-2)\cdot(3n-1)3n}=3^n$$